# Certificate issues running app in Windows 7

Tags: c#, certificate

I'm having some problems with my app. I'm using the 'org.mentalis.security' assembly to create a certificate object from a 'pfx' file, this is the line of code where the exception occurs:

`Certificate cert = Certificate.CreateFromPfxFile(publicKey, certificatePassword);`

This has always worked and still does in production, but for some reason it throws an exception when run in Windows 7 (tried it on 2 machines).

`CertificateException :
Unable to import the PFX file! [error code = -2146893792]`

I can't find much on this message via Google, but when checking Event Viewer I get an 'Audit Failure' every time this exception occurs:

```
Event ID = 5061
Source = Microsoft Windows Security
Task Category = system Integrity
Keywords = Audit Failure

Cryptographic operation.

Subject:
 Security ID:  NT AUTHORITY\IUSR
 Account Name:  IUSR
 Account Domain:  NT AUTHORITY
 Logon ID:  0x3e3

Cryptographic Parameters:
 Provider Name: Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
 **Algorithm Name: Not Available.**
 Key Name: VriendelijkeNaam
 Key Type: User key.
<BR>
Cryptographic Operation:
 Operation: Open Key.
 Return Code: 0x2
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working on Win 7, I've never had problems when I was running on Vista with this. I am running VS2008 as administrator but I guess that maybe the ASP.NET user doesn't have sufficient rights or something.

It's pretty strange that the 'Algorithm name' is 'Not Available'.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: when executing the same code from a winform app doesn't have this problem, so it seems this is related to the asp-net account in windows 7, anyone know wich rights to grant to this user to get this to work ?

Comment: I've tried adding user ASPNET to 'Cryptographic operators' group but that made no difference, even adding ASPNET user to 'Administrators' group did not do the trick !! I did have this working on my previous (Vista) installation. I have created a VPC windows XP SP3 and installed vs2008 on it, but on that machine the problem also persists... :( Does anyone have other suggestions ?

Comment: When running the webapp through cassini (not IIS) things work just fine. I'll have to check my production environment to see why it does work there ... :S

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Did you ever find out why it didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Corrected

Hi

I solved this by going to c:\windows\system32\inetsrv or syswow64\inetsrv

and running the following command

appcmd set apppool "[you app pool name]" -processModel.loadUserProfile:true

This solved it

Richard Allen

Answer (score 1):

In IIS 7 you can do this in IIS management console.

- Expand the server on the left
- Click on **Application Pools**
- Click on your website's application pool name and click **Advanced Settings** in the **Actions** pane on the right
- Under the **Process Model** section, change **Load User Profile** to **True**
- Click **OK**
- **Recycle** the App Pool from the Actions pane on the right
- **Restart** the website (expand **Sites** on the left, click on your website, click Restart in the actions pane.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by going to c:\windows\system32\inetsrv or syswow64\inetsrv

and running the following command

appcmd set apppool "" -processModel.loadUserProfile:true

This solved it

Richard Allen