# Accessing Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 from web application without .p12 file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 application with a separate class library for accessing the Google analytics data. Every try to use the common methods (loading the certificat from .p12 file) ends in an "internal error" (the file will be found!) in 3rd line (Dim certificat...)

```
    Dim scopes As String() = New String() {AnalyticsService.Scope.Analytics}
    Dim serviceAccountEmail = "info@xxx.biz"
    Dim certificate = New X509Certificate2(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Certificates/MyDashboard-b335c24b1a76.p12"), "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)
    Dim credential = New ServiceAccountCredential(New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail) With {.Scopes = scopes}.FromCertificate(certificate))

    Dim service = New AnalyticsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With { _
        .HttpClientInitializer = credential, _
        .ApplicationName = "MyDashboard" _
    })

    Dim MyRequest As DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest = service.Data.Ga.Get("ga:44582845", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "ga:sessions")
    MyRequest.MaxResults = 1000
    Dim MyResult As GaData = MyRequest.Execute()
```

> [CryptographicException: Interner Fehler.
>   ]
>      System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr) +41
>      System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromFile(String fileName, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx) +0
>      System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(String fileName, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) +307
>      System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags) +92
>      GoogleAnalyticsClient.Class1..ctor() in P:\Google Analytics\GoogleAnalyticsClient\Class1.vb:59
>      preisvergleich.Statistik.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in \web\Webs\AFFILIATE 2.0\preisvergleich\Statistik.aspx.vb:16
>      System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178

Is there any possibility to access the analytics data without the certificate (I think it was in former times)?

BR Jan

Comment: You can use Oauth2 and have the user authenticate themselves.  or you can use a Service account and only display data for the account the service account was given access to.

Comment: try adding:   X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable

Comment: I use the Service account, I took code from your side I think :-D (http://www.daimto.com/googleAnalytics-authentication-csharp/). But I already get the error when loading the certificate ...

Comment: Tried the "X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet" flag, new error message "Schlüssel ist im angegebenen Status nicht gültig." German. Must be "Key is not valid in the specified state." in English.

Comment: And for an overview, for the moment I want to access the statistics of my own Analytics account, no other.

Comment: then you are correct in using a service account.  I don't have the power of VB so cant give you a working example sorry.  The only examples I have are in C#

Comment: however "info@xxx.biz" <-- defiantly not a service account email address.

Comment: :-D I know, I use a real one

Comment: I will try the C# code from your site ...

Comment: Switched to C#, same "Internal Error". Checked the security eventlog and got an error 5061, so I must check the Server. Think the file itself cannot be corrupt.

Thanks for your help so far

Comment: It was an IIS configuration problem, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663011/certificate-issues-running-app-in-windows-7 solved it. Now I get new errors, but Google errors, so I will analyze it first.