# RabbitMQ: secure connection not working from web server to app server via IIS

Tags: ssl, iis, rabbitmq

I have an application server with RabbitMQ installed (Windows Server 2008 R2, RabbitMQ 3.6.5, Erlang 18.0).  I've set up SSL/TLS and have enabled the rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl plugin.  I'm having trouble getting my web server to successfully establish a connection to my app server.  However, this is only happening within IIS; a console app on the web server is able to connect to the app server.  I'm using certificate-based authentication here, and the console app has proven that this authentication works, so is there something special required in IIS to establish this kind of secure communication that is NOT required when using a console app?

The error I'm getting my my web app is:

```
[CryptographicException: An internal error occurred.
]
   RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne(IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector) +294
   RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName) +178

[BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable]
   RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName) +294
   MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.RabbitMqConnectionCache.SendUsingNewConnection(IPipe`1 connectionPipe, ConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +1463

[RabbitMqConnectionException: Connect failed: THEAPPSERVER:5671/VIRTUALHOST1]
   MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.RabbitMqConnectionCache.SendUsingNewConnection(IPipe`1 connectionPipe, ConnectionScope scope, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +1710
   MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.RabbitMqConnectionCache.Send(IPipe`1 connectionPipe, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +252
```

Thanks for the help,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

I found this StackOverflow post that solved my issue: [Certificate issues running app in Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663011/certificate-issues-running-app-in-windows-7).  In my scenario, I have an IIS app pool and website running as a **service account**, and I'm using a file-based cerificate to authenticate with RabbitMQ.  When I say "service account" I mean that the account appears under the "Log on as a service" policy when launching Windows "Local Security Policy" --> Local Policies --> User Rights Assignment --> Log on as a service.  There are 2 solutions to this problem:

1. As documented in the [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663011/certificate-issues-running-app-in-windows-7), in IIS --> Application Pools --> select the application pool --> Advanced Settings --> set "Load User Profile" from **False** to **True**.  [(Here's a blog that talks about what that setting does.)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity/)
2. Switch the IIS app pool credentials and website "Connect as..." credentials to a valid user with appropriate access, as opposed to running under a service account.

Hope this helps anyone struggling with the same issue.